# Como hacer que la información se guarde en un archivo txt durante la ejecución

Tags: java, netbeans, archivo

Mi duda es como lograr que datos de 5 personas que se ingresó desde el teclado se guarde en un archivo durante la ejecución, sin necesidad de que se termine la ejecución, para después (durante la misma ejecución) usando cualquiera nombre, me aparezca todos los datos de esa persona pero leyendolos desde el archivo.

Ya me crea el archivo y guarda la información en un archivo, y también lee la información de ese archivo. El problema es que la información que lee es la que se guardó en la ejecución anterior porque la que se acaba de ingresar aun no se a guardado en el archivo debido a que (supongo yo) la información se graba en el archivo hasta que la ejecución ha finalizado.

**Este es el código:**

```Java
package tarea;

import java.io.*;

public class Archivo {
    
    public void escribir(String archivo, String datos[]){
        File f;
        FileWriter fw;
        BufferedWriter bw;
        PrintWriter pw;
        
        try{
        
            f = new File(archivo);
            fw = new FileWriter(f);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            
            pw.write(datos[0]+"\n");
            for( int i=1; i<datos.length; i++ ){
                pw.append(datos[i]+'\n');
            }
            pw.close();
            bw.close();
            
        }catch(Exception e){
        
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    String[][] personas=new String[5][4];
    
    public Archivo(String nombre){
    
        try{
        
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(nombre);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            
            String temp = "";
            
            while(temp != null){
            
                for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
                
                    temp = br.readLine();
                    if(temp == null){
                    
                        break;
                    }
                    if(i < 4){
                    
                        personas[0][i] = temp;
                    }
                    if(i > 3 && i < 8){
                    
                        personas[1][i] = temp;
                    }
                    if(i > 7 && i < 12){
                    
                        personas[2][i] = temp;
                    }
                    if(i > 11 && i < 16){
                    
                        personas[3][i] = temp;
                    }
                    if(i > 15 && i < 20){
                    
                        personas[4][i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
        
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public String[] devolver_person( int indice ){
        return personas[indice];
    }
}
```

Comment: Eso me va a hacer que la información se guarde durante la ejecución y no hasta que se haya terminado de ejecutar el programa?

Comment: No me gusta el principio de tu código. Has esto: `String dato[20];for ( int i=0; i<datos.lenght; i++) dato[i]=datos[i];` y haci te dá una forma de escribir en el archivo mas facilmente: `pw.write(dato[0]);for( int i=1; i<dato.lenght; i++ ){ pw.append(dato[i]+'\n');}` o en ves de usar otro arrays datos usas el parametro de una vez: ` pw.write(datos[0]);for( int i=1; i<dato.lenght; i++ ){ pw.append(datos[i]+'\n');}`

Comment: Disculpa por editar tantos comentarios, pero el internet esta lento. Mira el codigo que te dí funciona de la misma manera que el codigo que tienes, pero con mas facilidad de lectura y mas facilidad de matenimiento. Se que no resolví tu ploblema, pero por ahora solo te dejo este consejo.

Comment: Sí, de hecho también quería preguntar sobre eso porque siempre me toca teclear mucho pero pensé que no era apropiado hacer dos preguntas diferentes en una. Gracias por el dato. sí me sirve.

Comment: Intenta editar tu código usando directamente el parametro `datos` para escribir el archivo. Nota: Java tambien acepta un arrays de mas de una dimenciones: `String[] a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,....,a30;` es lo mismo que: `String [][] a=new int[30][number];` la diferencia es que uno se puede llamar pasando el indice como parametro: `a[type][i]=String` y el otro nó: `atypei`=`ERROR var not defined.`